# Why node-sass-middleware is not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sass

I have installed the `node-sass-middleware` module on my express application, but i'm not getting that working, just because the middleware is reading an incorrect source, when i debug the console log is:

```
GET / 200 558.983 ms - 4651
  source: /home/karim/Snippets/my-financial/public/stylesheets/sass/stylesheets/main.sass
  dest: /home/karim/Snippets/my-financial/public/stylesheets/stylesheets/main.css
  read: /home/karim/Snippets/my-financial/public/stylesheets/stylesheets/main.css
```

which both directories are wrong, why the middleware is adding the string `stylesheets/` between the `source`/`dest` (`..public/stylesheets/sass/`) and the `.sass file`/`.css file` (`main.sass` and `main.css`)?

I have this configuration inside my `app.js`:

```
var sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');
...
...
var app = express();

app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets/sass'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets'),
  debug: true,
  indentedSyntax: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed'
}));
```

Obviously this is not compiling anything, becuase the directories are wrong.
Inside the `..public/stylesheets/sass/` folder i just have one file, `main.sass` which i want to compile and move the result outside the `sass/` folder, i mean at `..public/stylesheets/`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is because -- i am pretty sure -- on your html file there is something like that:

```
<head>

  <!--All your head stuff and-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css"/>

</head>
```

-- Lets call that href as yourAwesomeHref for a moment.

When your server receive any `get` request, the middleware will look for the *compiled* `main.sass` on `/home/karim/Snippets/my-financial/public/stylesheets` (`dest` option for the middleware) following by `yourAwesomeHref`, resulting this route:

```
/home/karim/Snippets/my-financial/public/stylesheets/stylesheets/main.css
```

Which that file obviously does not exist at all!
So you have to add `prefix: "/stylesheets"` on your middleware for avoid that problem.

**The final code is:**

```
var sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');
...
...
var app = express();

app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets/sass'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets'),
  debug: true,
  indentedSyntax: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed',
  prefix: '/stylesheets'
}));
```