# Why can't Sass see my .scss file in an Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, sass, handlebars.js

I'm building an Express app with Sass and I haven't made ANY changes to my project since I last compiled my .scss and .css files.

The command:

```
sass sass/style.scss style.css
```

was working the last time I worked on my project, but today I'm getting this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - sass/style.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Again, I've made NO NEW changes since this was last working, and I've even reverted to a previous git commit.

In my app.js, I have `node-sass-middleware` configured like this:

```
var sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');
```

and this:

```
app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets/sass'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets'),
  debug: true,
  indentedSyntax: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed',
  prefix: '/stylesheets'
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and my `public` file structure in `My-Website/public` looks like this:

```
├── public
    └── stylesheets
        ├── sass
            └── style.scss
        ├── style.css
        └── style.css.map
```

Also, in my `layout.hbs` file in my `views` folder (I'm using the handlebars templating language for Express), I have this link in my head:

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
```

What is going on?

Comment: Looks like you have a typo: `stylesheets/sass/style.scss`, not `sass/style.scss`

Comment: That results in the same error. And based on the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654312/why-node-sass-middleware-is-not-working, I was under the impression that Sass would be looking for the compiled `style.scss` at `My-Website/public/stylesheets` (which is the `dest` in the middleware configuration).

Comment: You have multiple components going on here, the command `sass` and `node-sass-middleware`, which uses the `sass` command to compile the sheets. In the beginning of the post you reference the `sass` command not working, and then you transition into your express script, which I assume means it also doesn't work. Check your current working directory, and ensure that it's `public/stylesheets/` when you run the first command

Comment: That worked, thank you! Just to clarify, the only problem was the sass command not working. Middleware was included in case that's where the problem lay. But either way, problem solved.

Comment: I'll paste my comment into an answer so you can mark it as answered (this is standard practice, IIRC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple components going on here, the command sass and node-sass-middleware, which uses the sass command to compile the sheets. In the beginning of the post you reference the sass command not working, and then you transition into your express script, which I assume means it also doesn't work. Check your current working directory, and ensure that it's public/stylesheets/ when you run the first command